# Why do custom made views with same properties have different size on different runs in Android

Tags: android, view, android-animation

I have a self-made custom view `View_Game_Event_Rectangle` which is just an orange rectangle with an icon at the beginning. I have a small fragment that just animates these rectangles from the right to the left of the screen. The really weird thing is that if I run the very same code multiple times, the length of the rectangles can be different from run to run altough I don't change anything, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

This is kind of weird because they have the same properties and sometimes they look equal but sometimes they don't if you compare different runs. Do you have any clue, why this is happening and how to tackle this issue?

Here is the Java file of the animating fragment class:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.game.databinding.FragmentTestBinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test extends Fragment {
    /*
    Game variables
     */

    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100;
    public static final double DIFFICULTY_SPEED_MULTIPLICATOR_INCREMENT_PER_LEVEL = 0.3;
    public static final int TIME_OF_A_LEVEL_IN_SECONDS = 90;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private int numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 = 8000;

    private int currentTimeSlot;
    
    private float verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine = 0.049f;
    private float percentageHeightOfEventElement = 0.071f;

    int widthDisplay;
    int heightDisplay;

    //Type of View_Game_Events
    public static final String VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR = "Solar";
    
    private FragmentTestBinding binding;

    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet ;

    //Variables for the single view event
    View_Game_Event_Rectangle[] viewEvent;
    boolean [] isViewEventActive;
    Drawable[] drawingsForTheViewEvents;
    private static int nextFreeIndexForViewEvent;
    private static int numberOfViewEventInArray = 10;
    ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle> arrayList_GameEventRectangles;

    private int [] orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel;
    
    private boolean fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

    private CountDownTimer cdt;

    private  final long DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER = 100; //100ms

    private int numberOfTimeSlotsUntilTheEndOfScreen = (int)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * 2/(DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER));


    public Test() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        nextFreeIndexForViewEvent = 0;
        viewEvent = new View_Game_Event_Rectangle[numberOfViewEventInArray];
        drawingsForTheViewEvents = new Drawable[numberOfViewEventInArray];
        arrayList_GameEventRectangles = new ArrayList<View_Game_Event_Rectangle>();
        isViewEventActive = new boolean[numberOfViewEventInArray];

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getWindowManager();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        widthDisplay = size.x;
        heightDisplay = size.y;


        container.getContext();
        constraintLayout= binding.constraintLayout;


        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        constraintLayout = binding.constraintLayout;
        constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        startGame();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void startGame () {
        startRound();
    }

    public void startRound () {
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel = new int[5000];
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel [74] = 25;
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel [83] = 25;
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel [92] = 25;
        orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel [101] = 25;


        //Create the array list with the Game_Event_Rectangles
        for (int i =0; i<orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel.length; i++) {
            if (orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel[i] >0) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.add(new View_Game_Event_Rectangle(getActivity(), VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR, i+1, orangeRectangleValuesForTheLevel[i]));
            }
        }

        countDownTime();

    }

    private void updateScreen() {

        /*
        Iterate through all elements
         */
        for (int currentElement =0; currentElement <arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {


            //Create view and set
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 15) {

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setActive(true);


                //Set the parameters and the backgorund of the view element
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));

                if(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getEventType().equals(VIEW_EVENT_RECTANGLE_SOLAR)) {
                    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.game_event_rectangle_bulb_1).mutate());
                }


                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setId(View.generateViewId());

                //Make the view invisible (before it's appearence time)
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(0);

                // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
                constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), percentageHeightOfEventElement);

                float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float)(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
                float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();


                constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
                constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID ,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

                float horizontalBias = 1.0f ;
                constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
                constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }
            
            //Shift the view to the right border of the display
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 10) {


                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth());
            }


            //Animate view element
            if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                View rectangle = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement);
                int rectangleWidth = rectangle.getWidth();
                float distanceToCover_current = widthDisplay + rectangleWidth;
                float distanceToCover_normalizedObject = widthDisplay + 20;
                double ratioDistanceDifference = distanceToCover_current /distanceToCover_normalizedObject;
                long durationForTheAnimation = (long)(numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * ratioDistanceDifference);

                arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay*(-1)).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();

            }
        }

    }

    private void countDownTime(){


        cdt = new CountDownTimer(100000, DELAY_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER) {
            boolean delay = true;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(delay) {
                    delay = false;
                } else {
                    currentTimeSlot++;

                    updateScreen();
                    delay = true;
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                updateScreen();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        // Reset your variable to false
        fragmentViewHasBeenCreated = false;

        // And clean up any postDelayed callbacks that are waiting to fire
        cdt.cancel();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

And there is the Java file of the custom made view:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class View_Game_Event_Rectangle extends View {

    private boolean isActive;
    private int numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing;
    private String eventType;
    private int startingTimeSlot;
    private int duration;

    public View_Game_Event_Rectangle(Context context, String eventType, int startingTimeSlot, int duration ) {
        super(context);
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.startingTimeSlot = startingTimeSlot;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing() {
        return numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing(int numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing) {
        this.numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing = numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing;
    }

    public void incrementNumberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing() {
        this.numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing = this.numberOfTimeSlotsAfterFinishing + 1;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public int getStartingTimeSlot() {
        return startingTimeSlot;
    }

    public void setStartingTimeSlot(int startingTimeSlot) {
        this.startingTimeSlot = startingTimeSlot;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

**Reminder**: Does any one have any idea as to why this strange behaviour can be observed? I am still having problems with this one

Comment: In view directly xml you can constraints

Comment: in xml  <com.example.game.View_Game_Event_Rectangle
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: @MeetBhavsar: Thanks Meet for your comment. Actually those custom views are created dynamically in the Java code and not in the XML code, as their properties vary (I create multiple of them with different properties). The shown code is just a minimal reproducible example. So specifying the rectangles in the XML file is not an option in my case.

Comment: @MeetBhavsar: Any further comments on my last comment Meet? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Answer (score -2):

I notice that the issue might stem from the usage of the `getWidth()` method of the `View_Game_Event_Rectangle` view in the `updateScreen()` method. The width of a view is not immediately available during the layout inflation process or when the view is first created.

To ensure that you have the correct width, you can postpone the retrieval of the width until after the view has been measured and laid out. Here's an updated version of the `updateScreen()` method that takes this into account:

```
private void updateScreen() {
/*
Iterate through all elements
 */
for (int currentElement = 0; currentElement < arrayList_GameEventRectangles.size(); currentElement++) {
    // ...

    // Set the ConstraintLayout programatically for the view
    constraintLayout.addView(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement));
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).post(() -> {
        // Get the width of the view after it has been measured and laid out
        int viewWidth = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getWidth();

        float widthConstrainPercentage_element1 = (float) (arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration() / 100.0);
        float duration = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getDuration();

        constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), widthConstrainPercentage_element1);
        constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);

        float horizontalBias = 1.0f;
        constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), horizontalBias);
        constraintSet.setVerticalBias(arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getId(), verticalBiasOfEventElementToBeInTheLine);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

        // Shift the view to the right border of the display
        if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot() - 10) {
            arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).setTranslationX(viewWidth);
        }

        // Animate view element
        if (currentTimeSlot == arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getStartingTimeSlot()) {
            arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).getBackground().setAlpha(255);
            View rectangle = arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement);
            int rectangleWidth = viewWidth;
            float distanceToCover_current = widthDisplay + rectangleWidth;
            float distanceToCover_normalizedObject = widthDisplay + 20;
            double ratioDistanceDifference = distanceToCover_current / distanceToCover_normalizedObject;
            long durationForTheAnimation = (long) (numberOfMillisecondsUntilTheMiddleOfTheScreen_Level1 * ratioDistanceDifference);

            arrayList_GameEventRectangles.get(currentElement).animate().setDuration(durationForTheAnimation).translationX(widthDisplay * (-1)).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        }
    });
}
}
```

By using the `post()` method, the code inside the Runnable will be executed after the view has been measured and laid out, ensuring that you obtain the correct width.

Please give this updated code a try and see if it resolves the issue with the varying lengths of the rectangles across different runs.

Comment: Thanks Sep for your answer. First of all when using your answer I get the error "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final" for the `currentElement`. I then used the quickfix by android studio and declared it final before your suggested code `int finalCurrentElement = currentElement;`. I ran the code but the general problem still persists. The rectangles have different lengths in different runs.

Comment: Thanks Sep for your answer (Just for your information: I did not downvote it and I think it is rude when someone downvotes an answer without explanation). Do you have any comment to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Any further comments, Sep?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, your suggested approach does not work. Do you have any other ideas? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Thanks Sep for your answer. Any further idea what I can try in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey SepJa, unfortunately your suggested approach did not work. Do you have any other idea for solving this issue. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.